# How can anonymous types be created using LINQ with lambda syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query that uses lambda syntax:

```
var query =
    books
        .Where(book => book.Length > 10)
        .OrderBy(book => book.Length)
```

I would like to create an anonymous type to store the projection, similar to:

```
var query = from book in books
            where book.Length > 10
            orderby book
            select new { Book = book.ToUpper() };
```

How do I "select new" in lambda syntax ?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: `select new` is not construct, it is selecting a new object. You can select everything, as well use anonymous new everywhere.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Like this:

```
var query =
    books
        .Where(book => book.Length > 10)
        .OrderBy(book => book.Length)
        .Select(book => new { Book = book.ToUpper() });
```