# .Select() in LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQ query

```
public List<RoleResource> GetAllRoleResources()
    {
        return this.GetAll<RoleResource>().ToList();
    }
```

I need to select only few columns like Column1, Column2 and a property BColumns, which is another table and has a relation to the main table. How will I retrieve this using .Select()....I had used the following :

```
.Select(row => {row.Column1, row.Column2, row.BColumns}).ToList()
```

Its not working and showing error too. Whats the correct syntax for .Select() ?

Comment: You need to instantiate an object of anonymous type. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645494/how-can-anonymous-types-be-created-using-linq-with-lambda-syntax - basically, you're missing `new`.

Answer (score 3):

Define a view model containing the columns you are interested in:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string BColumns { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
.Select(row => new MyViewModel 
{
    Column1 = row.Column1, 
    Column2 = row.Column2, 
    BColumns = row.BColumns
}).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

"**new**" keyword should be added for instantiation. Following is the **correct syntax and code** for the .Select() in LINQ to work properly.

```
.Select(row => new{
        row.Column1, 
        row.Column2, 
        row.BColumns})
.ToList()
```

It will work properly.

Comment: Hi..I did applied..but I am getting an error while applying. The code is as follows :                                           public List<RoleResource> GetAllRoleResources()
        {
            return this.GetAll<RoleResource>().Select(row => new
            {
                row.RoleID,
                row.ResourceID,
                row.Actions
            }).ToList();
        }                                                              Error is highlighting aT .ToList();...it says conversion issue...Cannot implicitlity convert the System.Collections.Generic.List to

Comment: should I have to give any conversion ? I have edited my code in the question...please check