# How to Get the Names of Only the Selected Properties?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, reflection

The scenario is like this:
- EF stored procedure returns 5 columns as DataResult
- All I need is 3 columns, so I coded

```
var data = (from i in db.GetDataResult()
               select new DataResult
                 {
                   prop1 = i.prop1,
                   prop2 = i.prop2,
                   prop3 = i.prop3,
                     }).ToList();
```

- Without hard coding string names, I would like to get the names of the selected columns, that is prop1, prop2, and prop3.

How to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: `typeof(DataType).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.Contains("something")).Select(p => p.Name)` will return the names of all properties containing "something". You can use that `Where()` clause to filter on anything. Instead of `select new DataResult`, you can use an anonymous object that just contains the fields you're looking for. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645494/how-can-anonymous-types-be-created-using-linq-with-lambda-syntax for example.

Comment: If I select anonymous, I get the error that can't convert anonymoustype to IList or IEnumerable. But what then would be the benefit of using anonymous over specifying the type?

Comment: It is working on anonymous type as well, `var s = x.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.Contains("something")).Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand. You are saying that you don't need the filter, you already have done that; you're wanting to get the mapped column name. First see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7929287/593090).

That said, based on @John Arlen's answer:

```
foreach (var prop in data[0].GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, Type {1}", prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
}
```

The problem here is that this should normally give you:

```
prop1, *some type*
prop2, *some type*
prop3, *some type*
```

The confusion is that you are somehow specifying columns before you know the names, and yet in your code example you *are* using the column names. The columns that you specify should match the column names; `prop1` in your code should correspond to the column `prop1` in the data source. You were implying that you wanted to filter which columns to get (and which columns to *not* get) based on the column names.

So this is assuming that you already know beforehand *which* columns you want, based on some other (unspecified) criteria; that is, if you know that you are getting `prop1`, `prop2`, and `prop3` but not `propX` or `propY`. Obviously you can't get the column/property names *before* you filter columns/properties if you don't know the names.

**Edit**

It occurs to me that you may be wanting to determine which fields are getting filled, and which are not. This *might* work if you *know* that none of the fields are null:

```
foreach (var prop in data[0].GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (prop.GetValue(data[0], null) != null)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, Type {1}", prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
}
```

**Edit 2**

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313008/how-can-i-extract-the-database-table-and-column-name-for-a-property-on-an-ef4-en?lq=1).

Comment: Thanks for your persistence. data[0].GetType().GetProperties() based on null or not null that is exactly what I needed - I didn't see that part in John's answer. And you are correct that I knew beforehand which columns I want based on "unspecified" criteria - I thought that was clear - my mistake. And regarding the example, I assume that you know that prop1, 2, and 3 are not hard coded strings, or in other words, you can grab them using intellisense. Thanks for the helpful links as well.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined by Steve, the Where() can be used to filter:

```
List<string> names = GetDesiredListOfNamesSomehow();
var props = typeof( DateTime ).GetProperties()
       .Where( i => names.Contains( i.Name ) ).Select( i => i.Name );
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Prop Name: " + prop);
}
```

However if you know the names to filter, you do not need to request the names.  So I assume you are trying to get the actual properties themselves:

```
var props = typeof( DateTime ).GetProperties().Where( i => names.Contains( i.Name ) );
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, Type {1}", prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
}
```

Comment: But that still will require writing the property names by hand in advance as strings - as you did in new string[] {"Date", "Day", "DayOfWeek"}; However, what I am looking for is to get the names of prop1, prop2, and prop3 from var data, as mentioned in the main example in order to avoid messing with strings.

Comment: How do you plan to identify *which* properties you want?

Comment: That is what I was trying to accomplish. The first step was to select or filter only the columns/properties which I need from a DB stored Proc, as I did in the second code example in the main post...Second, I was hoping that using reflection or any other technique to get the names of the properties/columns which I selected/filtered in step one.

Comment: The hard-coded strings above were an example. Use whatever source (database or whatever) as inputs.

Comment: The issue is that the source, in this case the stored proc, is returning columns more than I need. Since I don't have much control of DB stuff, I wanted to use the data I got and filter the columns I need, then get the names of those filtered columns/properties.

Comment: I still don't understand; how can you filter first (using the column names) without knowing the names, and *then* get the column names? Are you not filtering which columns you want based on the column names?

Comment: Neither do I, I don't understand. You say: _I wanted to use the data I got and filter the columns I need_. And so... you are the only one who knows what columns you need!

Comment: @klugerama and nlips, I don't know what so hard to understand about this. The code above is so clear. I selected properties/columns without hard coding strings - this is done. Now, how to get the names of those selected properties - programmatically?